# parsing a string with a double and getting error input string was not in correct format

Tags: c#, csv

I have a string from a csv file that looks like this ""711,200.00"" I am trying to convert that number to a double with this code

```
collaterel.LoanQty = double.Parse(values[25], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I have taken out the comma and tried to convert to a double and I still get input string was not in correct format

This is what I used to take out the comma

```
  if (values[25].Contains(","))
  {
     values[25] = values[25].Replace(",", "");
  }
```

I have tried many culture this still fails.

screen shots double.parse with cultureinfo does not work

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Friendly reminder not to use `double` for currency.  Use `decimal`.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1165788/1563833)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `double.Parse("711,200.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` [works](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4eJ0L3), but your input is `""711,200.00""`, you just need to trim the quotes:

```
collaterel.LoanQty = double.Parse(values[25].Trim('"'), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In general you should use `double.TryParse` to avoid catching exceptions with invalid formats.

Comment: You addressed the real issue, the one that was ignored by me :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `double.Parse`.

```
var s = "711,200.00";

Console.WriteLine(double.Parse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number));
```

prints

```
711200
```

[NumberStyles.Number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=net-5.0) is

> Number    111
>
> Indicates that the AllowLeadingWhite, AllowTrailingWhite, AllowLeadingSign, AllowTrailingSign, AllowDecimalPoint, and AllowThousands styles are used. This is a composite number style.

Comment: the type isn't a decimal its a double

Comment: No drama, let's make it double.